# Calculating in XSLT

Tags: xslt, math

I have an .xsl which works perfectly, but when I add this line to it, it just doesn't display anything:

```
<xsl:variable name="K1"><xsl:value-of select="600 - (108 * 300 / 150)"/></xsl:variable>
```

I suppose this is more likely a syntax error but I can't find it. Did I have something particular to do to calculate in XSLT?

Comment: What development environment are you using? You should get a clear error message for this both in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. The only time you might not is if you are running this code in the browser and not looking at the developer console. You need to think about your development and testing process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XPath/XSLT the operator for division is `div`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="600 - (108 * 300 div 150)"/>
```

---

Note that when assigning a variable it is better to do:

```
<xsl:variable name="K1" select="600 - (108 * 300 div 150)"/>
```

This way the variable contains the actual number 304, instead of a text node as it does using your method.

Comment: @Gajiu: do you display the variable somewhere? Your code only assigns it. If you're not sure, remove the xsl:variable for a moment

Comment: My bad, it works perfectly I just forgot to put "$" before my variable name. Thx guys.